# Find closest row with simple formula compared to a given row in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, math

In a mathematical formula, I want to calculate the difference or similarity as, difference equal `sqrt(s1 - t1)^2`, so the square root of the difference between `Value1` of seed row and `Value1` of comparison row, squared. Where `S1` equals `value1` of seed row and `T1` equals `value1` of comparison row.

To calculate the overall similarity or difference of the seed row to comparison row:

```
[sqrt(s1-t1)^2]+[sqrt(s2-t2)^2]+[sqrt(s3-t3)^2]+... = Similarity
```

So for example using the table below, `ID1` is the seed row, and `Id2` is the comparison row, and then `ID3`, then `id4` and so on will be the following comparison rows.

```
[sqrt(3-1)^2]+[sqrt(4-5)^2]+[sqrt(3-3)^2]+[sqrt(5-5)^2]+[sqrt(0-4)^2]+[sqrt(1-1)^2]
+[sqrt(3-2)^2]+[sqrt(4-4)^2] = 2 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 4 + 0 +1 + 4 = 12
```

Going down the list,

```
ID1 to ID2: 2 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 4 + 0 + 1 + 4 = 12
ID1 to ID3: 1 + 1 + 1 + 4 + 4 + 0 + 2 + 1 = 14
ID1 to ID4: 0 + 0 + 0 + 3 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 1 = 6
ID1 to ID5: 1 + 0 + 0 + 4 + 0 + 4 + 3 + 3 = 15
```

So from that formula, it has been determined that Row `ID4` is the best match to Row `ID1` because it has the lowest number.

```
ID   |  Value1  | Value2  | Value3 | Value4 | Value5 | Value6 | Value7 | Value8 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |    3     |    4    |    3   |    5   |    0   |    1   |   3    |    4   |
2    |    1     |    5    |    3   |    5   |    4   |    1   |   2    |    4   |
3    |    4     |    3    |    2   |    1   |    4   |    1   |   1    |    5   | 
4    |    3     |    4    |    3   |    2   |    1   |    2   |   3    |    3   | 
5    |    2     |    4    |    3   |    1   |    0   |    5   |   0    |    1   |
```

I am using PHP and MySQL and I would like to know how to I achieve the above explained?

Comment: Squaring the square root of the difference will give you a value which will be approximately equal to the difference. Are you sure you're using the right formula or may be I am missing out something.

Comment: Yes,  I am sure it is the proper formula. The reason I am squaring the square root is because it will always result in a positive result. This question does not have to be answered with the formula in play if it is complicating things. I am just trying to figure out the most efficient way of looping through every row to do a comparison. Once I have the results, I can then find the square of the square root.

Comment: If all you want is the positive value of the difference, you may use `abs()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php

Comment: Please share the code that you have implemented so far

Comment: Abs() would work, but now how would I go about looping through the mysql table and get the sum of each column comparing the seed row to the comparing row as I stated in my original post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find the rows closest to a specific row, you may use a query like this,
in which every row is joined to the seed row, and the results are ordered by the calculated difference:

```
SELECT t2.*, ABS(t1.v1-t2.v1)+ABS(t1.v2-t2.v2)+ABS(t1.v3-t2.v3) AS diff
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id=1) AS t1
JOIN tbl AS t2 ON t1.id <> t2.id
ORDER BY diff;
```

If you want to find the differences between each pair of rows, a query like this will do:

```
SELECT t1.id AS t1_id, t2.id AS t2_id,
       ABS(t1.v1-t2.v1)+ABS(t1.v2-t2.v2)+ABS(t1.v3-t2.v3) AS diff
FROM tbl AS t1
INNER JOIN tbl AS t2 ON t1.id <> t2.id
ORDER BY t1.id, diff;
```